# how can i get the id of some hardware if i work with eclipse galileo 3.5

Tags: eclipse-plugin

hi my name is marcel i'm very interesting in learn how to get the id of different component of the computer(MotherBoard, Hard Disk, Prossesor), i work with eclipse galileo 3.5 as a Java Text Editor (www.eclipse.org), can somebody tell me wich one is the plugin for eclipse to work with JACOB or with JCom, my email is marceljch@gmail.com if you can send me the answer to my email will be really helpfull for me, thank's

Answer (score 0):

There was a plugin in 2004 introduced [at IBM alphaworks](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/dtjcb?open&S_TACT=104AHW61&S_CMP=GR&ca=dgr-eclpsw02awdtjcb), but removed since then.

The closest one still active would be [OLEJA - OLE for JAva (OLEJA)](http://oleja.javain-ltd.qarchive.org/), another Java COM bridge based on OLE automation.

[image: Java COM Class Generator]

Otherwise, you need to come up with your own wrapper (based on the [JACOB project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/develop)),
or, like SWT used by eclipse, look at [MSA MicroSoft Active Accessibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Active_Accessibility), since leveraged by IBM with its [IAccessible2 project](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/accessibility/iaccessible2).